# Can I publish asp.net core with sdk and runtime files?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

I am working to publish my project to vps server Linux
Can i publish project from visual studio with sdk and runtime files
without install sdks and runtime to my server ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you publish you can chose to include all the packages needed by the project by making it "self contained" here is the command line to build it:

```
dotnet publish -o c:\temp\yourproject --self-contained -r linux-x64
```